# How do I implement L.C.M (1 to N),N>2, using recursion or any other method?

Tags: c, math, recursion

I've been trying to implement L.C.M(1,2,....,20) in C language by prime factorization. I've searched all over Google but they're only methods for two variables.
I've written this code:

```
int lcm(int a[i],int n)
{
//n is the nth number to find L.C.M, for eg: LCM(1,2,...,20) Here,N=20
//a[i] is the list of primes upto n;
     K=sqrt(n);
     while(pow(a[i],k)>n)
         K=K-1;
     P=P*pow(a[i],k);
/*My idea over here is to make a list of primes up to 'n' and store them in list a[i]. Then for each each prime in the list,the power of that prime should exceed 'n'.
For eg: Let, N=10 .. K=3 ,
             Pow(2,3)=8<10
So,P=1*8,and for the remaining primes {3,5,7},it can be represented in prime factorization:
P=2^3 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^1 = 2520.
}*/
```

I've problems in implementing it because I don't know much about Arrays and I think this algorithm is not so efficient. 
I am much interested in finding LCM(1 to N) using recursion or any other efficient way.Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the fastest way to do this is to know two properties of `LCM`.

1. `LCM` is associative. That means that `LCM(a,b,c) = LCM(LCM(a,b),c)`. This allows you to find the `LCM` of a large number of numbers while only ever calculating the `LCM` of two of them. Basically, you start with `L = 1`, then loop `i=1` to `20` and `L = LCM(L, i)`.
2. `LCM(x,y)*GCD(x,y) == x*y`, which implies that `LCM(x,y) == x*y/GCD(x,y)`. [Euclid's algorithm for GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is faster than factorization, so you can use this to quickly calculate LCM.

With these two properties, you should be able to design a quick `LCM` system without any complex datastructures or algorithms.

Here's a skeleton of a code snippet for the case `[1, 2... 20]`.

```
int L = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <=20; i++){
    L = LCM(L,i);
}
// L contains the LCM of 1 to 20
```

Comment: What if I want to compute LCM( 1,2,3...10) ..Then How should I do it?
Is there an algorithm to calculate LCM up-to N?

Comment: @VanuAparna Yes, see part 1 of my answer. You start with `L=1`, then loop from `i=1` to `10` and let `L = LCM(L, i)` at every step. `return L` at the end.

Comment: I think I understood it. But can you please show that logic in code snippet,so that I can have better understanding.

Comment: I think that what you call GCF (presumably an abbreviation for Greatest Common Factor) is normally called GCD (greatest common divisor).  At least, that's the English name; GCF might be a direct transliteration of the term used in some other language.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm actually a native speaker myself. I always assumed that GCD was preferred in Britain and GCF in the US, but I could be wrong. (My formal training in number theory has been limited to grade school, in which GCF is frequently used).

Comment: Not sure what to say.  [AcronymFinder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/GCF.html) lists 'Greatest Common Factor' as the top match for GCF.  The Wikipedia page you link to uses GCD throughout, except where it says _Synonyms for the GCD include the greatest common factor (GCF), the highest common factor (HCF), and the greatest common measure (GCM)._  I'd not heard of GCF that I can recall, but it wasn't hard to guess from the context.  Ah well, language is a funny business...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, that's interesting. I remember distinctly first learning GCF in elementary school and first hearing about GCD in a cultural context (that show is pure GCD) -- I guess the British thing comes from the fact that I've learned math through a British site and if GCD is accepted within the math community, I just associated the mathematical community with Britain :-)

Answer (score 2):

Prime factorization is not an efficient way to compute `lcm(a,b)`. A good way to implement it is by using the formula:

```
lcm(a,b) = a / gcd(a,b) * b
```

Now, a simple and yet efficient algorithm to compute `gcd(a,b)` proceeds as follows:

```
Set n := a; m := b.
While {n != 0} do {s := n. n := m % m. m := s}.
Return abs(m)
```

where `m % n` stands for the modulo operation, i.e, the remainder modulo `n`.

Now that we know how to compute `lcm(a,b)` we can proceed recursively:

```
lcm(a[i],k)
    if k = 1
      Return a[0] / gcd(a[0],a[1]) * a[1]
    else
      Return lcm(lcm(a[i],k-1),a[k])
```

Comment: What if I want to compute LCM( 1,2,3...10) ..Then How should I do it?
Is there an algorithm to calculate LCM up-to N?

Comment: Let's start small. lcm(1,2) = 1/gcd(1,2)*2 = 1*2 = 2. lcm(1,2,3) = lcm(lcm(1,2),3) = lcm(2, 3) = 2/gcd(2,3)*3 = 6. lcm(1,2,3,4) = lcm(lcm(1,2,3),4) = lcm(6,4) = 6/gcd(6,4)*4 = 6/2*4 = 12. lcm(1,2,3,4,5) = lcm(lcm(1,2,3,4),5) = lcm(12,5) = 12/gcd(12,5)*5 = 60. Keep adding 6, 7, etc. to the sequence until you get lcm(1..10). Also, use the algorithm I described in my answer to compute the gcd of two numbers. Do not use prime factors as that is too costly in terms of performance.